# Download string from private github repository with token

Tags: c#, curl, github

well i need to get a content of a single file in a Private Github Repository but my problem is that I can't find a way to make my code work to the github authentication:

I found at the Github API that I can do a CURL request to get that but I don't know how to make a curl at C#

```
            curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com
            curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN

            var client = new HttpClient();

            // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
            var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_token", "keeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey"),
            });

            // Get the response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/file.text",
                requestContent);

            // Get the response content.
            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

            // Get the stream of the content.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Write the output.
                Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
```

any ideas ?

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet)

Comment: I can't connect with login and pass only with Token